# JQuery UI slider 'slide' function not setting angularJS value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to display the slider values below it by capturing the values from the [`Slide`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) function and setting it to AngularJS `$scope` variables but it isn't working.

This is my JS code snippet:

```
$( "#price-slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000000,
    values: [ 10000,  500000],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $scope.price_gt = ui.values[0];
        $scope.price_lt = ui.values[1];
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="price-slider"></div>
<p style="text-align: center">&#8377; {{price_gt}} - &#8377; {{price_lt}}</p>
```

Can anybody please help me understand where I'm going wrong? I basically need to get the value dynamically as the user moves the slide and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with AngularJs and not JQuery Slider.

Making this change solved my problem:

```
slide : function(event, ui) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.price = {
                        lower_limit : ui.values[0],
                        upper_limit : ui.values[1]
                };
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="price_gt" size="auto" readonly style="border:0; color:black; font-weight:bold;  width:100% " />
```

Comment: This does not help at all and is not how AngularJS works AFAIK